# Vue3/Pinia computed from storeToRefs

Tags: vuejs3, computed-properties, pinia

I have a situation where I need to create a computed property from a pinia store getter -

```js
import { computed} from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import {useMyStore} from './../stores/mystore'
export default {
  setup() {
    const { sessionUser } = storeToRefs(useMyStore())
    const fullName = computed( () => 
      `${ sessionUser.value.value.firstName } ${ sessionUser.value.value.lastName }`
    )
    return {
      fullName
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously the `value.value` is clunky, and I'd rather not move the computed property down into the store itself.  I know *why* the `vale.value` is necessary, but is there any better way to set up a computed reactive property in a component that is based on a store value (which is also a computed property within the store)?

Comment: Computed properties are like getters in Pinia. Just don't use getters and create composable that return computed property if you want to have it reusable. If not, just make computed in a component setup function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// In your store.js or store.ts file
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';

const pinia = createPinia();

export const useStore = pinia.createStore({
  state: () => ({
    originalList: [], // Your original list
    filteredList: [], // Filtered list
    searchTerm: '', // Search term
  }),
  getters: {
    // Computed array for the filtered list
    computedFilteredList: (state) => {
      return state.originalList.filter(item =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(state.searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      );
    },
  },
  actions: {
    // Action to update the search term
    updateSearchTerm(newTerm) {
      this.searchTerm = newTerm;
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<!-- In your component.vue file -->
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="searchTerm" placeholder="Search">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in computedFilteredList" :key="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from './store';

const store = useStore();
const searchTerm = ref(store.searchTerm);

const computedFilteredList = computed(() =>
  store.computedFilteredList
);
</script>
```